# CSS nth-child expression to avoid the last row with at most 3 elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am creating lists that display in columns of three, every `<li>` has a `border-bottom` like so:

```
x | x | x
---------    
x | x | x
---------      
z | z | z
---------  

<ul>
    <li>x</li><li>x</li><li>x</li>
    <li>x</li><li>x</li><li>x</li>
    <li>z</li><li>z</li><li>z</li>
</ul>
```

What I wish to do is create an nth-child expression to remove the `border-bottom` on the last line of three, so for the above example that would be:

```
ul li:nth-child(-n+6) {
    border-bottom:0;
}
```

**The Problem**

However where it get's slightly more complicated is that the amount of items in the list varies so any of the following scenarios could come about:

**Scenario 1**

```
x | x | x
---------   
x | x | x
---------   
z |
---  

<ul>
    <li>x</li><li>x</li><li>x</li>
    <li>x</li><li>x</li><li>x</li>
    <li>z</li>
</ul>
```

**Scenario 2**

```
x | x | x
---------   
x | x | x
---------   
z | z |
-------

<ul>
    <li>x</li><li>x</li><li>x</li>
    <li>x</li><li>x</li><li>x</li>
    <li>z</li><li>z</li>
</ul>
```

**Scenario 3**

```
x | x | x
---------   
z | z |
-------

<ul>
    <li>x</li><li>x</li><li>x</li>
    <li>z</li><li>z</li>
</ul>
```

**Conclusion**

My aim is to always remove the `border-bottom` on the last row (or in this example the character **z**) so that it does not have the style applied to it.

An ideal soloution would be:

```
ul {
    padding-bottom:-20px;
}
```

But `padding-bottom:-#px;` is not supported in CSS.

The only other way I can think of to do this is to create an nth-child expression to capture only rows that include 3, that aren't the last line?

I guess it may need some sort of division by 3 to look for the amount to apply it too?

Comment: Are you using list elements? ul>li>li? You could do it using divs by wrapping each row in a div.

Comment: will you please add html also

Comment: @Steven I'm just using ul > li, I know it could be done easier by ul > li > ul > li styling but it adds a lot more code which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Silver89 , just to find a creative way... will your elements always be no more than 9 ? Are they always of the same height? Is acceptable for you a different solution involving only css?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan the most elements would be 24, ideally I'd like to use just css as it's an integral design part of the page and with javscript/jQuery sometimes there may be slight delays. If worst happens I'll use `ul li ul li` and have rows of 3 `ul li`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So far, I've created a selector that applies a style to the last row

```
/* all the cells */
li {
   background: #ccc;
}

/* last row, doesn't matter how many cells */
li:nth-last-child(-n + 3):nth-child(3n + 1), /* first element of the last row */
li:nth-last-child(-n + 3):nth-child(3n + 1) ~ li /* all its following elements */
{
   /* reset the style, eg: */
   background: transparent;
}
```

You can see a live example here http://jsbin.com/ufosox/1/edit

Of course this doesn't support IE8 and less.

Comment: +1: Amazing! I like this because you found a nice way to apply different rules to actual elements (not only a fake background-color as in my example). Unfortunately IE8 is still widely used ;(

Comment: Ah, yes, an override with `:nth-child()`, `:nth-last-child()` and a sibling combinator. I should add that you can simplify the selector to `li:nth-last-child(-n + 4):nth-child(3n + 3) ~ li` (or, even more simply, `li:nth-last-child(-n + 4):nth-child(3n) ~ li`), which counts `li:nth-last-child(-n + 3):nth-child(3n + 1)` as a sibling without you having to select it individually.

Comment: Actually, @BoltClock, your selector is different from mine in the case only one row exists, as yours doesn't include it while mine does it http://jsbin.com/ufosox/7/edit I would say that the "correct" solution depends on the final effect one wants to achieve.

Comment: I don't really understand how your nth-child works, could you please explain?

Comment: Fantastic! @Silver89, the `li:nth-last-child(-n + 3)` matches the last 3 items, which may span part of the last 2 rows). This selection is narrowed by `:nth-child(3n + 1)` which selects the _1st_ item of _all rows_. Used together, _both must be true_ before the selection occurs: the last row is _contained_ in the 1st selection (whether 1-3 items long) and the 1st item of the last row by the 2nd selection, resulting in selecting the 1st item in the last row (as he commented). Then, using that selector with the sibling combinator `~` selects all remaining last row items that follow the 1st item.

Comment: @electric_g you r my hero

Answer (score 10):

Instead of nth-expressions, maybe a simple css solution is enough?

Set *border-bottom* to every LI, and *overflow:hidden* to the UL. Then move every LI 1px down so that the last line is hidden.

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/7uGRq/

Answer (score 4):

Since I can't see a way to achieve your desired result using `nth-*` pseudoclasses only, I've tried to be creative : if your list-items have all the *same height* (e.g. suppose `30px`), a workaround involving only css could be done in this way

http://jsbin.com/ukubug/4/edit

CSS

```
ul { list-style: none;  
     margin: 3em 0 0 0; padding: 0;
     height: auto; overflow: hidden; 
     position : relative;
}

li { float: left; width: 30px; height: 30px; 
     position: relative; z-index: 1;
     text-align: center; line-height: 30px;  /* just to h/v centering */
}

li:nth-child(3n+1) { clear: left }


ul:before {
   position: absolute;
   z-index : 1;
   content : "";
   display : block;
   background : #f00;
   left    : 0;
   top     : -30px;  /* this is the height of your list-items */
   width   : 100%;
   height  : 100%;
}
```

The trick is to apply a background color to `ul:before` pseudoelement, give it an absolute position and then apply a negative top offset equal to a `li` height.

The `overflow : hidden` applied to `ul` will work both as a clearing method and to cut the red layer positioned outside its parent boundary. At the same time you need to position also `li` elements, so they can overlap `ul:before`.

Please note that if you have less than 4 `li` elements you won't see any highlighting effect (since your *first* row is also your *last* row): if you need to highlight always *at least one row* (partially filled or not) just apply a

```
min-height : 60px;  /* double height of a li element */
```

to `ul:before`.

hope it could be helpful.

---

As final consideration, note also that this solution itself <sup>(*)</sup>

- should work fine even on `IE8`, while a solution relying on `nth-*` pseudoclasses won't work on that *pseudobrowser*
- it's easily scalable if you switch to a `2/4/5/6/`... column layout.

<sup>(*)</sup> well, this requires a different method to obtain a `clear: left` on `3n+1` li elements, of course :)

Comment: What my actual aim is ... all li elements have a `border-bottom`, in the last row I am trying to hide this border and apply `border:none;` to those elements. Thes easiest way would be `ul {padding-bottom:-20px;}` but this is not doable as there's no support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have access to the HTML code itself, but if you do, my perfect solution would be to add another html div AFTER the ul, give a background color of white, a height of 30px, and top or margin-top of -30px (or whatever needed to hide the last chunk of the ul)

```
<ul>...</ul>
<div style="background-color: #fff; height: 30px; margin-top: -30px">&nbsp;</div>
```

an another note, you tried padding-bottom, but did you try margin-bottom: -20px?

Answer (score -2):

I'll suggest that you apply a style to all your li, then do a specific rule for the last one :

```
ul li:last-child {
    background-color:#FF0;
}
```

Please note that :last-child is not compatible with IE LTE 8 (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Comment: that will change the last item, not the last row of items

Comment: It's not like `:nth-child()` is any more compatible either.